# Issue with sending multiple ajax requests

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable in which the first column contains some links to display the details for each item. I am using f:ajax to send the request to the action listener.

While it does work for the first time (when I click the first link *or any link*) but after that it stops working and no request is sent to the actionlistener.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{inquiry.myObject.property}"
                                actionListener="#{myBean.getDetail}">
                                <f:param name="someName" value="#{someBean.someName}"/>
                                <f:ajax
                                    render=":#{p:component('infoDisplay')}
                            :#{p:component('addFieldSet')} :#{p:component('myDetailsId')}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

How do I make sure that the request is generated for every link and not just for the first attempt ?

[image: sample table]

UPDATE---

here is the action listener

```
public void getDetail(ActionEvent event) {
 String xyz=context.getRequestParameterMap().get("someName").toString();
//some task
}
```

I have set a breakpoint on the first line of this function. This function gets called only once (for the first time).

After the first successful ajax call, I can see the below error in developer tools.

```
customer?p_p_id=account_WAR_XXX&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=6&p_p_col_pos=1&_account_WAR_XXX_javax.faces.resource=primefaces.js&_account_WAR_XXX_ln=primefaces&v=4.0:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
```

Comment: [mcve] please !

Comment: added my listener as well.

Comment: [mcve] please !

Comment: You are btw using a pre-historic version of PrimeFaces. Lots of fixes and improvments have been made since then.

Answer (score 0):

replaced `<f:ajax render> with <p:ajax update>`. I no longer see the javascript bug on the developer tools and all the functionality seems to work as expected.